Is there a way to have Awesome Window Manager without a GUI?
I have the Budgie flavour of Ubuntu installed. I have installed the Awesome Window Manager. Can you have Awesome without a GUI? Will my programs still run normally?
I don't just text-based terminal programs, stuff like Visual Studio Code. Can you load only Awesome and have your graphical-based programs work like normal or is Awesome alone only going to enable you to use Text-based terminal programs?

GUI stuff will still require a graphical stack to run on top of, with "all the programs" do you mean that programs you use are restricted to executables that run in the shell and TUI-based programs?

Okay so if the programs are graphical then a GUI is required. So there is no foregoing the GUI completely.

Yeah you'll need something to run GUI stuff. However there are intermediate solutions such as lightweight desktop environments (such as XFCE / Xubuntu, heck even MATE would be lighter than GNOME) and tiling window managers such as i3 (often used by those who mostly use the terminal but don't want to forgo the GUI completely - those very much differ from the typical desktop environment though, as everything is focused on using keyboard shortcuts)

Don't forget GUI is a rather large term; if on a very low powered device (32-bit x86 for example) I tend to skip any desktop and just use a WM (window manager) alone, as I do like to control my windows with the mouse (it isn't much fun in my view using terminal to re-draw windows) & I do like borders/buttons (close/minimum etc or WM functions)....   Budgie is a desktop, you've not said what release but it maybe  budgie-window-shuffer (24.10 for example) being the WM used by the Budgie Desktop is sufficient... What you need will depend on what you'll use

I have played with awesome window manager and it seems to be what I want. Is there a way to get awesome without the GUI? I will make an edit.

add .desktop file to $HOME/.config/autostart/

I am not totally clear on what you are asking - because Awesome Window Manager  itself has a GUI - a Graphical User Interface.   But this is what you can do.
I installed Awesome Window Manager on a 20.04 virtual machine I keep for testing.  (Its original desktop is MATE).  After doing that and rebooting, you are presented with the choice of logging into Awesome instead of one of the Ubuntu desktops.

If you pick that and log in, this is what you get. There is nothing much on the desktop, but right-clicking gives you menus.

I think this is what your goal is. It lets you run graphical programs. They are listed in the right-click menu.
